# How to read an excel file from fileInputNode in IIB?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I want to read and process an excel file from a fileInputNode. What has preprocessing has to be done. WHat message format should I use. what property settings have to be applied on the fileInputNode.

The other solution is to create a java application and read the file ,create 1 message for every row and put in the queue. That is a lenghty process,I want to read it directly from the IIB FileInput Node.

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

You first start by saying Excel file, but then talk about processing row by row.  If you're not actually trying to process an xlsx file but can get the data in a csv file then have a look at the Records and Elements tab of the properties on a FileInputNode. If you change the Record Detection property to Delimited, you could process the file one record at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built support for .xlsx files in IIB. You'll have to read it as BLOB in your FileInput Node and then parse it using any available Java Libraries. See [this](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=55686) link from mqseries.net for reference.